# AttributeError when looping through Django User objects

Tags: python, django

When looping through a QuerySet of User objects in Django, I keep getting an AttributeError when trying to access each User objects related set of another model.

**models.py**

```
class List(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title   

    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owned_lists')
```

**utils/emails.py**

```
def daily_completed():

    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        # get one big QuerySet
        all_lists = user.owned_lists.all()
        print all_lists
```

When my "daily_completed" function runs, it triggers the following AttributeError when trying to lookup each user's 'owned_lists':

*AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'owned_lists'*

**BUT** when I alter the 'daily_completed' function to just run on behalf of one user, and not loop through all the users, it works fine.

**example utils/emails.py**

```
def daily_completed():

    user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    # get one big QuerySet
    all_lists = user.owned_lists.all()
    print all_lists
```

The above function works fine, and doesn't trigger any AttributeError.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening? I'd really appreciate some help here! Thanks in advance.

Here is the entire traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\projects\slothnote\env\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\projects\slothnote\env\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\projects\slothnote\env\slothnote\lists\tasks.py", line 14, in daily_completed_tasks_email
daily_completed()
File "C:\projects\slothnote\env\slothnote\lists\emails.py", line 30, in daily_completed
all_lists = user.owned_lists.all()
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'owned_lists'
```

**UPDATE:**

No clue why, but when I change the names of the variables I'm looping through. See here:

```
all_users = User.objects.all()
for each_user in all_users:
    # get one big QuerySet
    all_lists = each_user.owned_lists.all()
    print all_lists
```

The above block executes as expected. So, my problem is solved but I'm still really interested to know why it didn't work before.

Comment: can you catch the attribute error in the loop and inspect the user that is triggering it? What pk does the user have that is trigggering it? What type, what is the object that is triggering it? Is it saved? how are you executing daily_completed? Also please post the complete traceback when asking a question

Comment: Thanks for your help! The loop is raising an AttributeError when it encounters the very first user object in the QuerySet (pk=1). If I remove the loop, and instead directly get this user object (as shown in 'example uitls/emails.py') the function executes as expected. The user is saved, yes, and daily_completed is being executed as a periodic task via Celery. I've updated the question to include the entire Traceback just FYI.

Comment: And this is the type of the object: <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>

Comment: Do you use `user` as a var inside the emails.py (not in your function) or somewhere else as a global?

Comment: @petkostas I don't, no.